# Is there a open source RDP protocol server for Windows Home Edition?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

Is there a open source RDP protocol server for Windows Home Edition, like xrdp for Linux?  I figure that since Linux can server RDP protocol to Windows Terminal service clients, then there must be a open source RDP server that a person can install on Windows Home edition?

I am not looking for any of the VNC variants.  My question is about RDP protocol only.

Comment: Windows has inbuilt support for remote connections via RDP without additional software (enable remote connections). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Windows "Home" doesn't come with that feature. Not in Windows 7 and it didn't with Windows XP either.

Comment: I suggest you make this question about Home edition then. Corporate editions (including Ultimate) certainly do support inbound remote connection (for support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm relatively sure there are no open source RDP server implementations for Windows.

Comment: Thanks.  I just wanted someone else to verify my suspicion.